# VS2015, #endregion is missing how to find it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Is there quick way to find missing #endregion buried in code, the compiler error always point to end of C# code with no indication where it is missing.

Comment: look for the `#region`. either remove it, or understand what it is surrounding.

Comment: No, because you need to decide where the right position for `#endregion` is.

Comment: how is the compiler supposed to know where you want your region to end? Check where your region starts and place the end where you want it to be

Comment: This is the moment to [let go of regions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/) ... just search and remove them all.

Comment: Not helpful comment there......is there 3rd party extension that to find it.

Comment: Look for the region that wont collapse... but as @Filburt mention let go of the regions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Press Ctrl + M , O // Collapse all functions and regions;
2. Press Ctrl + F and type #region // Scroll down from Begin of the class;
3. It will clearly show like below Screenshot with no + sign but other region will have + sign;
4. You can notice closed-region will be collapsed in grey color and '#region' will be not visible but open-region will be shown as in the Screenshot;
5. Note : If you don't know where should be the #endregion, then either delete the 
   '#region' or write #endregion just below the start #region;
6. Then error will boom.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for a `#region|#endregion` with regex flag on. Then look through search results for correct structure. If you do not have nested regions, they should alternate. If you have, I expect you to have correct indents, so first `#region` without `#endregion` with same indent in previous line is what you are looking for.

Note that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for searching in a single file too.

Comment: Nope I have hundred of hundred of #region in code, I'm looking for quick solution if available.

Comment: Use the above regex to replace all regions with emptyness!